# why the second writeline print out 12 when using lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, functional-programming

code below

```
    int factor = 2;
    Transformer sqr = x => x * factor;
    Console.WriteLine(sqr(3)); // 6
    factor = 4;
    Console.WriteLine(sqr(3)); // 12
```

I think lambda should capture factor in the compile time, so the result should be the same for the two writeline.

However, when I run, I get 6 and 12, so does the C# lambda use dynamic scoping?
I thought lambda should use something called "lexical scope"

Comment: Perhaps you want to use [`Lazy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: What do you mean by "lexical scope"? The `factor` variable is in scope throughout your code here.

Comment: what do you mean to use "lazy" here?

Comment: @Lasse, I thought when a variable is captured, the variable and value are both captued; seems that I am wrong in c# perspective.

Comment: Lazy accepts a Func in its constructor and would calculate the Func once. So `Lazy<int> lazy = new Lazy<int>(() => x * factor);` would give you the same value everytime that you call lazy.Value.

Comment: @Default This has nothing with variable catching, it is just memoization.

Comment: Yes, it captures the variable, not the value. Rawlings answer answers this portion of it. The local variable is promoted to a field on a generated class and the code is rewritten to access the method on that generated class through that delegate.

Comment: @Default, could you give me a working example which I can try. If using lazy, I expect to get 6 always right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is copying performed when capturing a value-type into a lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982125/is-copying-performed-when-capturing-a-value-type-into-a-lambda)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wMZgNM it's not an answer to your current question, I know, but I figured it might be an easier solution if it's simply the value that you want to store between "prints".

Answer (score 4):

First of all you cannot capture anything at compile time. The environment for the lambda can only be captured at runtime, because that's the only time when it exists.

When a variables is captured by a lambda then the lambda has in effect direct access to that variable for the entirety of its lifetime; changes to the value from outside will be seen by the lambda (google "access to modified closure") and the reverse is also true.

It follows that if you want to isolate the lambda from outside interference you have to *make it capture something that noone from the "outside" will have access to* -- that means a variable whose scope has been sufficiently limited.

Consider:

```
int factor = 2;
Func<int, Func<int, int>> generateTransformer = f => x => x * f;
Func<int, int> sqr = generateTransformer(factor);

Console.WriteLine(sqr(3)); // 6
factor = 4;
Console.WriteLine(sqr(3)); // 6
```

What happens here is that `sqr` is the result of calling `generateTransformer` and it is capturing the value of the local variable `f` inside the body of `generateTransformer`. That value can never be changed by anyone because it cannot be seen by anyone outside the body of `generateTransformer`. Calling `generateTransformer` makes a copy of the current value of `factor` and gives that "frozen" copy to `sqr` to use.

Answer (score 2):

It *does* capture `factor`. It captures it as a member variable of a hidden closure class, along with a method for the lambda. You end up with something approximately similar to

```
private class sqrClosure
{
    public int factor;
    public int srq(int x)
    {
        return x * factor;
    }
}

...

var c = new sqrClosure();
c.factor = 2;
Console.Writeline(c.sqr(3));
c.factor = 4;
Console.Writeline(c.sqr(3));
```

Comment: is this "lexical scope"; I think lambda should use "lexical scope"?

Answer (score 1):

It does capture `factor`, but it captures the *variable* not the *value* of the variable.

So when you change the variable, and then call the lambda, it's taking the current value of the captured variable.