# Unity3D Coroutines and lambda callbacks: memory leak safety

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda

Is it safe to invoke System.Action that was declared in a coroutine?

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine(){
     bool myBool = true;
     System.Action action = ()=>{myBool=false;}

     StartCoroutine (MyOtherCoroutine(action));//just launch and forget about it
 }

 IEnumerator MyOtherCoroutine(System.Action dangerous_callback){
     yield return null;
     yield return null;//skip several frames
     yield return null;
     dangerous_callback.Invoke();//will cause problems? The owner coroutine (and it's myBool) is no longer on stack
 }
```

My concerns are about `myBool` that was allocated within the first coroutine. `MyCoroutine` doesn't wait until `MyOtherCoroutine` completes. I can see that System.Action won't be collected because it's indeed still referenced by `MyOtherCoroutine`, but `MyCoroutine` (whose boolean variable the Action modifies) should have already be deallocated?

Comment: Did you run into issues or are you asking if it is fine to do this?

Comment: I though it's convenient to use callbacks within coroutines, because it's not possible to use 'ref' or 'out' arguments. But this seems like a possible memory leak, that might be impossible to catch later on? Just asking if it's fine to use it

Comment: If you want to know the reason / mechanics of why this is safe the search term is "delegate closure capture"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this seems like a possible memory leak, that might be impossible
>   to catch later on? Just asking if it's fine to use it.

*No memory leak*. It's totally fine to do that and that's what to do if you need a callback in a coroutine function. Remember that this is C# and it's harder to create memory leak in C# than with C++ unless you're misusing some of Unity's API which can create memory leak on the native(C++) side but that's not the case here.

Although, you should check if the `Action` is `null` before calling it otherwise, expect some issues in you code.

```
if (dangerous_callback != null)
    dangerous_callback.Invoke();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really weird, because myBool belongs directly to MyCoroutine, I would assume Action would try to access some de-allocated memory. I always thought of them as functions that are removed from the execution-stack once } is reached. So in c# this original coroutine will be kept until my callback is invoked?

Comment: `Action` is a `delegate` which is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). When you pass it to another coroutine function, GC will allow it to live until that coroutine function exist. It will never be freed if there is a reference of it anywhere. When `MyOtherCoroutine` is done executing, no reference to it exist so it can now be collected by GC.

Comment: Sorry for being so stubborn :D but what about myBool that was allocated within the first coroutine? `MyCoroutine` doesn't wait until `MyOtherCoroutine` completes. I can see that System.Action won't be collected because it's indeed still referenced by `MyOtherCoroutine`, but `MyCoroutine` (whose boolean variable the Action modifies) should have already be deallocated?

Comment: No problem. Coming from C++ you will have many questions when using C#. *"MyCoroutine (whose boolean variable the Action modifies) should have already be deallocated?"* No. Since it is referenced in the `Action` reference type or the `action` variable, the compiler will move the `myBool` variable into a helper class. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982125/is-copying-performed-when-capturing-a-value-type-into-a-lambda) post. Since you used lambda, it creates a closure.

Comment: I would add you can write that in one line using the null-propagation operator: `dangerous_callback?.Invoke();`

Answer (score 0):

shortly you can use:

```
dangerous_callback?.Invoke();
```

Comment: The question was, about variables that the `dangerous_callback` intends to work with. Not about the callback itself